# jOOQ - create value for field

Tags: sql, api, alias, jooq

I have a Field `Field<T>`. I want to create a named value for that field, to be able to use it in a query. The name of the value should be the name of the field.

```
select value as field from ...
```

Is the the correct way to do it?

```
public <T> Field<T> namedValue(Field<T> field, T value) {
    return DSL.val(value, field).as(field);
}
```

Although it works, I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do this. I might be pedantic here :).

**update**

I am creating the following construction:

```
UPADTE table SET x = alias.x, y = alias.y
FROM (SELECT constant value for x, table2.y FROM table2 WHERE ...) AS alias.
```

Let's simplify this to (for the sake of this example, to focus on the constant selection):

```
SELECT
FROM (SELECT constant value for x) AS alias.
```

First, I started with:

```
Select s1 = context.select(DSL.val("TEST"));
Select s2 = context.select(s1.fields()).from(s1);
```

This resulted in an incorrect query:

```
select "alias_66794930"."TEST" from (select 'TEST') as "alias_66794930"
```

(I am not really sure if this is correct behavior from jOOQ.)

So, I added an alias:

```
Select s1 = context.select(DSL.val("TEST").as(X));
Select s2 = context.select(s1.fields()).from(s1);
```

This resulted in:

```
select "alias_76324565"."x" from (select 'TEST' as "x") as "alias_76324565"
```

This works fine. Then, I ran into problems when the constant vale was null:

```
Select s1 = context.select(DSL.val(null).as(X));
Select s2 = context.select(s1.fields()).from(s1);
```

This resulted in:

```
select "alias_85795854"."x" from (select cast(? as varchar) as "x") as "alias_85795854"
1400 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding  - Binding variable 1       : null (class java.lang.Object)
```

This makes sense, the field type is not known. So I added the field (with its type) as following:

```
Select s1 = context.select(DSL.val(null, X).as(X));
Select s2 = context.select(s1.fields()).from(s1);
```

Binding is now correct:

```
1678 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding  - Binding variable 1       : null (class java.lang.String)
```

All done!

Comment: What's the use-case? Is `Field<T> field` a field from a table, typically? So you want to substitute a table column with a constant?

Comment: @LukasEder It is indeed a field from a table. It is intended for a `update table set ... select ... from ...` statement. Some of the projections in the `select` clause are constants, and that's where I wanted to use the function above.

Comment: Hmm, but you don't need to name those constants, do you? Perhaps, could you update your question with an example `UPDATE` query that illustrates the use-case?

Comment: @LukasEder I added some history how I came up with the question. See my edit of the question. It also explains why I had to name the constant.

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks for the update! There's another pending feature request somewhere that should generate column names in nested selects for standalone bind variables - can't seem to find it right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can get much shorter than what you already have. I mean, your SQL reads:

```sql
value as field
```

And your Java/jOOQ code reads:

```java
DSL.val(value, field).as(field)
```

You could of course static import `DSL.val` or `DSL.*`:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

And then shorten things to:

```java
val(value, field).as(field)
```

And if you're very sure about `value`'s type, you don't need to coerce it to that of `field`

```java
val(value).as(field)
```

Now, you definitely can't go any shorter, and there's no more need for your `namedValue()` function...

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! The only open question now is if the jOOQ is correct with the query `select "alias_66794930"."TEST" from (select 'TEST') as "alias_66794930"` (see edit of original question). That's why I had to add the alias.